# gitlab import command issues and clarification

Tags: import, gitlab

I have got following commands for gitlab repos import but I am unable to understand this. Can anyone explain the each syntax of this command??

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does execute the task "[`lib/tasks/gitlab/import.rake`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/tasks/gitlab/import.rake)" which contains the comment:

```
# How to use:
#
#  1. copy the bare repos under the repos_path (commonly /home/git/repositories)
#  2. run: bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
```

Its full documentation is at "[`doc/raketasks/import.md`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md)"

So there is no special arguments to pass to that command: simply copy the bare repos where they need to be for GitLab to manage them, and complete the import process with that command.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are not clear about this but the repo to be imported:

- it must end in `.git` (common convention for bare repos)
- it must be placed under a user / group namespace, e.g.: `repositories/username/repo.git`. If the namespace does not exist, it gets created as a group.

I have proposed doc improvement at: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/8140